# what's the default hex/rgb/color when you hover the input type button?

Tags: css, colors, hex

what's the default hex/rgb/color when you hover the input type button?
`<input type="button" value="hover here"/>` OR `<button>"hover here"</button>`
and when you hover that button what's the hex color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hover `<input type="button/>"` or `<button>` the color is the same note that the selector is:

```
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
button {
    ...
}
```

On the other hand the color when you hover depends on the browser because each browser has it's own styling e.g

Chrome: `buttonface` `rgb(221, 221, 221)` = `#dddddd`

IE: `rgb(166, 244, 255)` = `#a6f4ff`

FF: `-moz-buttonhoverface` (define a gradient in hover)

and above even depends on the theme being used.